# Create a colormap in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colorbar, colormap, contourf

I have a contour plot with data that goes from -90 to 90 degrees. for now i am using jet so I have a map that looks like this [image]

I have been asked to change the colormap so that instead of having a gradient, I have a fixed color for each 5 degress (so I believe 36 colors). Also i was thinking of maybe having same colors for the interval [5 10] and [-10 -5], and so on if that makes sense.

My code is quite long because i have a lot of data to process, but that's part of it just so you can see what function i am using to plot this

```
%%
x1=data(:,5); %x location
y1=data(:,16); %y location
z1=phi*90; %angle phi
z2=gamma*90; %angle gamma
n=300; precision of grid

%Create regular grid across data space
[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(min(x1),max(x1),n), linspace(min(y1),max(y1),n));

figure(3);
contourf(X,Y,griddata(x1,y1,z1,X,Y),100,'EdgeColor', 'None')
%title('Variation of In-plane angle \phi')
axis equal
axis ([0 8000 0 12000]) 
axis off
h=colorbar;
caxis([-90 90])
set(h, 'YTick', [-90:15:90])
```

Does anyone know how to create this colorbar? 
Cheers

Comment: www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html , all you want is there

Comment: Thanks I just looked at it, i think i figured out how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every colormap-generating function in Matlab, including `jet`, takes an argument that specifies how many colormap entries there should be. In your case, you want 180 / 5 = 36 discrete colors:

```
colormap(jet(36))
```

To make sure the 36 colors cover exactly the 5 degree steps, set the color axis explicitly:

```
caxis([-90 90])
```

The result looks e.g. like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank A. Donda. It works fine, also what I did is create my own colormap matrix so that way I can have -90 and +90 the same color ( requested by my superrvisor because they are actually the same)

Comment: You're welcome. Good that you already have it, otherwise you could have used a periodic colormap like `hsv`: starts with red and ends with red, and uses the whole spectrum of colors.

Comment: Yeah, use a hue colormap like `hsv`, jet is horrible in more ways than one...

Comment: @rubenvb, agreed, `jet` is ugly.