# Creating a heatmap/colormap in Matlab, by mixing two colors

Tags: matlab, matrix, heatmap, color-mapping, colormap

Hey I have two big matrices 400x400. That I want to create into one heatmap/colormap. Current code:

```
res = matrix_1*256/2 + matrix_2*256/2;
%res = res -max(max(res));
HeatMap(res)
surf(res,'EdgeColor','none');
view(0,90);
colormap(gray);
colorbar
disp('done');
```

where the heatmap function everyone can look up. But to give a visualization of the second one it results in:
[image]

This however does not let me know which matrix is dominant. But only that both are dominant (white) both are not dominant (dark). I would like to make a plot where I use fused data. E.g. Matrix 1 is nuance of red and Matrix 2 is nuance of green:

> rgb = [matrix_1(i,ii), matrix_2(i,ii), 0]

then I want to make a 2D plot using the color that rgb represents. Is this possible ? I have looked at making my own colormap (but you guessed with no good results).

I have found solutions like [this (how-to-create-an-interpolated-colormap-or-color-palette-from-two-colors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851050/how-to-create-an-interpolated-colormap-or-color-palette-from-two-colors) and [create-a-colormap-in-matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262269/create-a-colormap-in-matlab), but I how do I specify a specific colour for every point in a 2D plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
RGB = cat(3, matrix_1, matrix_2, zeros(size(matrix_1)));
imshow(RGB)
```

Now the chart will be black were neither are dominant, red where `matrix_1` is but `matrix_2` is not, green where `matrix_2` is but `matrix_1` is not and yellow where they both dominate.

If you wanted, you could even convert this back to an indexed image and get the `colormap` that colours it this way using [`rgb2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html) and then create a surface plot using your original `res` for the heights (note there is no longer a need to scale this) and your new indexed image (`ind`) to specify the colours which are no longer enitrely goverened by height

```
res = (matrix_1 + matrix_2)/2;
[ind, map] = rgb2ind(RGB);
surf(res, ind, 'EdgeColor','none');
colormap(map)
colorbar
```

Comment: Even though you said not sure! It is spot on! Thx But snippets work for different scenarios. :)